# Keep getting "socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lvm1SGO" 404 errors when I deploy on server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, browserify

My app works fine on localhost but once I upload it I keep getting "socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lvm1SGO" 404 errors that keep listing in the console.
Sorry if this is a stupid question but I am fairly new with socket.io.
Here is where you can inspect and see the error in action: http://95.211.186.223/projects/webrtc/work/P2PImage/

My client.js file:

```
// this file is meant to be browserified
var P2P = require("socket.io-p2p");
var io = require("socket.io-client");
var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
var socket = io();
var opts = {autoUpgrade: true, peerOpts: {numClients: 10}};
var p2p = new P2P(socket, opts);
var $ = require("jquery");

p2p.on("peer-num", function(num) {
  console.log("You are peer number " + num);
  $(".peerNum").html( "Number " + num );
});

p2p.on("file", function(stream) {
  //console.log(stream);

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob(stream));
  document.getElementById("receivedImages").appendChild(img);
});

$(function() {
  $("#file").change(function(e) {
    ss.forceBase64 = true;
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var stream = ss.createStream();

    ss(socket).emit("file", stream, {size: file.size,name:file.name});
    var blobStream = ss.createBlobReadStream(file);
    var size = 0;
    blobStream.on("data", function(chunk) {
      size += chunk.length;
      console.log(Math.floor(size / file.size * 100) + "%");
    });
    blobStream.pipe(stream);
  });
});
```

My server.js file:

```
var app = require("express")();
var express = require("express");
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var p2pserver = require("socket.io-p2p-server").Server;
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
var path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
io.use(p2pserver);

var peerNum = 0;


io.on("connection", function(socket) {

  console.log("Peer " + peerNum + " connected");
  io.emit("peer-num", peerNum);
  peerNum++;

  ss(socket).on("file", function(stream, data) {

    var filename = path.basename(data.name);

    var parts = [];

    stream.on("data", function(data) {
      parts.push(data);
    });

    stream.on("end", function() {
      socket.broadcast.emit("file", parts);
    });

  });
});

    server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Listening on 3000")
});
```

Comment: Looks like here is an apache server: http://95.211.186.223/projects/webrtc/work/P2PImage/socket.io

Socket.io is only available in the node.js script. You either have to add a proxy to apache or install nginx, or change the port the express server is listening to.

Comment: I see. Thank you.
You mentioned "or change the port the express server is listening to". Meaning that there is a solution that doesn't use ngnix?
If so, how do I accomplish that?

Again. Really sorry for the stupid questions. I am very new at this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You problem is that you are trying to contact an nodejs server on an apache server.

This does look like this:
[image: Description Apache]

The problem is that Apache doesn't know how to handle the incoming Socket.io request. The simplest option now is to expand the server and let socket.io connect to another port:
[image: Description Apache and Socket.io]

So everything is the same as before.

In this example setup, you have Apache installed on a dev server (like the one you mentioned). You have access to the servers shell.

1. Transfer your files holding the express and socket.io files to the server (besides the web root directory, not in /var/www. I would recommend to put it in /home/myUserName/[productname]).
2. Make sure that nodeJS and NPM is installed on the server
3. If you didn't transfer node_modules, execute `npm install` to install the packages.
4. Set the port to something other than 80 - probably 3000. Remember this number.
5. Start the server as you do on your client (`node index.js` or something similar)
6. If you access your server now via port 3000 (http://myServerDomainOrIp:3000) you should get the same results as on the client. But you want (or have) to use the apache web server. So open in the apache web files the file which starts the socket.io client. There should be a line around this: `var socket = io();`. Change this to `socket.connect('http://myServerDomainOrIp:3000');`

So static files are serverd over apache, but the socket.io connection is established with the nodejs server.

I hope you understand a bit right know. Apache and Socket.IO is a bit complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me out so much.
I managed to fix the issue and I fully understand where I went wrong previously.

Comment: Great explanation @Larce.  What is the best option between the ones you pointed? "add a proxy to apache or install nginx, or change the port the express server is listening to"